# Why does the TextMate title bar not show the file path when opened with the "mate" command?

Tags: macos, textmate

When I open a file in TextMate using the `mate` command the title bar does not allow me to right click to see the path of the file while files opened within the TextMate app do show the full path.  Is there something about the behavior of the `mate` command that prevents this functionality or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to have the path visible in the title bar the `mate` command must include the full path of the file.  Using `mate` with an assumed current working directory (CWD) does not inherently provide `mate` the full file path.

Comment: This might be a bug (or feature request) as this would mimic the behavior of opening a file from finder.

Comment: One of the reasons I am about to switch to sublime.

Comment: How can such a mature editor not have this as an option?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a local project .tm_properties file it's trivial to have TM2 display the path - add something like:

```
windowTitle = "$TM_DISPLAYNAME – $TM_DIRECTORY"
```

Works with `$ mate [filename]` in terminal and in normal finder use.

But I agree it's pretty lame that it doesn't seem to work for the global .tm_properties - though I'd love to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to folder "/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources" or where your TextMate.app installation folder. Close textmate app before modifying the file.
2. Modify the file Default.tmProperties as below. I have provided the diff here:

   diff Default.tmProperties
    ../textmateBin/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/Default.tmProperties
   10c10

   ### < windowTitleProject = '${projectDirectory:+ — ${projectDirectory}}'

   > windowTitleProject = '${projectDirectory:+ — ${projectDirectory/^.*///}}'
3. Restart your textmate app and it should display your folder path :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot trying to figure out where that properties file was on my mac. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think TextMate has updated the documentation on their website.
It even contains a similar snippet to solve the issue above.

> For example, if we want to show the path as relative to the project
>   folder, we can use:
>
> ```
> windowTitle = '${TM_DIRECTORY:+${TM_DIRECTORY/^${projectDirectory}(?:\/(.+))?/${1:+$1/}/}}$TM_DISPLAYNAME$windowTitleProject$windowTitleSCM'
> ```

Source: https://macromates.com/textmate/manual/projects